# Copy file during Team City Build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, webdeploy

I've got an MVC 5 project stored in Git.  I've installed TeamCity 9.1.7 (build 37573) on our build server and I've set it up to successfully perform a build when a developer checks in code to Git.  My goal is to deploy the MVC application using MS Web Deploy if the build is successful.  I've seen a number of tutorials that suggest using a web deploy package, but these tutorials are six or more years old. Is this still the preferred method for deploying a successful TeamCity build to IIS?

Further, we've added the web.config file to gitignore for a number of reasons.  Git houses as Web.config.base that developers will copy to their own web.config file as a starting point.  A developer will copy the web.config.base file to web.config when they first pull down the project.  I've tried to set up a command line task in TeamCity to xcopy the web.config.base file to web.config

```
Working Directory: (left blank)
Command: xcopy MyMVCProject\Web.config.base MyMVCProject\Web.config
```

This build step fails with exit code 4 at all times.  I've set the TeamCity build agent service to run as a local administrator.  I've tried this as straight command text as above, as a cmd or bat file, and with a variety of different path styles, going so far as to use the TeamCity working directory variable, excluding the MyMVCProject from the path, including the MyMVCSolution in the path, etc.  Any ideas as to why the xcopy would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same problem I was facing.

But at last, we put the master web.config file on the server where TeamCity is installed.

Then once the Project gets deployed , I replaced the web.config file with the web.config file which is alreay present on server.
So there will be no conflict in the web.cofig file

You just need to add one more build step after the Web deploy step.
In that you can use Xcopy and you can replaced you web.config file

Hope this will work

Comment: Out of curiosity, my command line build step to xcopy keeps failing. I've tried with batch/cmd file and with straight up command line syntax.  Could you post an example of what you've used?  Did you specify a working directory yourself or did you allow TC to specify it?

Comment: Check this image for Command line runner : http://screencast.com/t/tWWcdbQa7a

Script should look like this : 

xcopy /y C:\_works\Teamcity\webconfigfiles\Demo_Project\Web.config C:\_works\_projects\DemoProject\websites\API\v1\Web.config

Here, 1st you have to put your web.config on Server and then you can replace that file where your project is publish.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

WebDeploy is still a great option for deploying ASP.NET web applications.  Its even used with the brand new ASP.NET Core framework.  We don't use TC but do you WebDeploy/MSDeploy extensively at work to deploy 50+ applications.

Regarding your config setup, I've never seen this approach.  We use Parameterization to handle config changes per environment (local dev included). If you're worried about security of the config values, you could secure your SetParameter files which have the sensitive info and include the web.config in source control with default or placeholder values.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: It's not about security.  We've got a separate web.config transform for each build configuration.  The developers each have different databases and settings for our application when developing locally.  Rather than have to stash the web.config every time before we push or pull Git changes, we decided to stop tracking the web.config and only track a base copy of the web.config.  Your answer doesn't quite touch on my interest in TeamCity, but thank you for your response.